# looping through multimap values

Tags: scala

I have a scala multimap which looks like this

```
Key: fish value: Set:(salmon,batam fish, shark)
Key: winged animals value: Set:(chicken, ducks)
```

I have a string text which looks like this:

```
val string = "the market had sold salmon and chicken"
```

As the string contains salmon and chicken, i need to return back the keys fish and winged animals.

Is there a way to iterate through the value sets and return a key if there is a match?  I can loop through key value pairs but i can only get the multimap as shown above and not the individual values.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
val index: Map[String, Set[String]] = Map(
  "Fish" -> Set("salmon", "batam", "shark"),
  "Winged Animals" -> Set("chicken", "ducks"),
  "Other" -> Set("cow", "pig")
)

def typesInString(search: String): Set[String] = index.filter {
  case (t, vals) =>
    vals.exists(search.contains)
}.keys.toSet

typesInString("the market had sold salmon and chicken")
// Set(Fish, Winged Animals)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a reverse Map from the MultiMap for value-key lookup, as below:

```
import collection.mutable.{ Set, HashMap, MultiMap }

val text = "the market had sold salmon and chicken"

val mm = new HashMap[String, Set[String]] with MultiMap[String, String]

mm.addBinding("fish", "salmon")
mm.addBinding("fish", "batam fish")
mm.addBinding("fish", "shark")
mm.addBinding("winged animals", "chicken")
mm.addBinding("winged animals", "ducks")

val reverseList = for {
  mList <- mm.toList
  mValue <- mList._2
}
yield (mValue, mList._1)

// Use groupBy instead of toMap (*)
val reverseMap = reverseList.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// reverseMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[String]] = Map(
//   salmon -> List(fish), ducks -> List(winged animals), chicken -> List(winged animals),
//   shark -> List(fish), batam fish -> List(fish)
// )

text.split("\\s+").collect{
  case x if reverseMap.contains(x) => reverseMap(x)
}
// res1: Array[List[String]] = Array(List(fish), List(winged animals))
```

(*) Note that `groupBy`, instead of `toMap`, is applied to `reverseList` to allow an animal belonging to multiple groups; which is also why the result is a nested collection (e.g. a bat could belong to List(mammals, winged animals)).

Answer (score 0):

Without looping through key-value pairs, using only own `MultiMap` methods, we still have to loop through the keys:

```
val items: MultiMap[String, String] = ...

val string = "the market had sold salmon and chicken"

val matched = items.keys.filter(key => items.entryExists(key, string.contains(_)))

println(matched)
// Set(winged animals, fish)
```